# Working with Zip and GZip files in Java

Tags: java, file-io, zip, gzip

It's been a while since I've done Java I/O, and I'm not aware of the latest "right" ways to work with Zip and GZip files. I don't necessarily need a full working demo - I'm primarily looking for the right interfaces and methods to be using. Yes, I could look up any random tutorial on this, but performance is an issue (these files can get pretty big) and I do care about using the best tool for the job.

The basic process I'll be implementing:

- Download a bunch of files (that might be zipped, gzipped, or both) to a temp folder.
- Add all the extracted files to a new zip file in a temp folder.

The input files might be compressed and archived more than once. For example, the "full extraction" should take any of the following inputs (I'm not in control of these), and leave behind `foo.txt`:

- `foo.txt.gz`
- `foo.txt.zip`
- `foo.txt.gz.zip`
- `foo.txt.zip.gz`
- ...
- `foo.txt.gz.gz.gz.zip.gz.zip.zip.gz.gz`
- ...

Then, I might be left with `foo.txt`, `bar.mp3`, `baz.exe` - so I would just add them all to a new zip file with some generic name.

#### Questions:

- With file size being a potential concern, which (interfaces/classes/methods) should I use to *quickly*:

  - extract zip files?
  - extract gzip files?
  - write zip files?
- Am I better off keeping the individual extracted files in memory before writing back to the disk? Or,
- Do potentially large files make that a bad idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that TrueZip, the library suggested below, has been superseded by [TrueVFS.](http://truevfs.net/)

---

I've found the [TrueZIP library](https://christian-schlichtherle.bitbucket.io/truezip/) useful.  It allows you to treat archive files as if they're just another file system and use the familiar Java I/O APIs.

Unlike the `java.util.zip` API, TrueZIP provides random access to the contents of the archive, so file size should not be a concern. If I remember correctly, it will detect archive files and not try to redundantly compress them when you put them into an archive.

Quoting the TrueZIP page:

> The TrueZIP API provides drop-in replacements for the well-known classes `File`, `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream`. This design makes TrueZIP very simple to use: All that is required to archive-enable most client applications is to add a few import statements for the package `de.schlichtherle.io` and add some type casts where required.
>
> Now you can simply address archive files like directories in a path name. For example, the path name `"archive.zip/readme"` addresses the archive entry `readme` within the ZIP file `archive.zip`. Note that file name suffixes are fully configurable and TrueZIP automatically detects false positives and reverts back to treat them like ordinary files or directories. This works recursively, so an archive file may even be enclosed in another archive file, like in `outer.zip/inner.zip/readme`.

Comment: Thanks. I ended going with TrueZIP, and after a little bit of frustration (due to not grokking it), it's worked beautifully.

Comment: FWIW, java.util.ZipFile provides memory mapped random access as well:   http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/

Comment: @reve_etrange would you mind to update the link or explain what you mean?

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20101026174612/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/

Comment: FWIW, The article is still available on Oracle's site: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/compress-1565076.html

Answer (score 11):

Don't hold all this uncompressed data in memory, or you might run out of heap space. You need to stream the data out to file when uncompressing and then stream it back in from file when you want to create your final zip file.

I haven't done zipped files before, but here is an example which shows how to uncompress a *gzipped* file:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.zip.*;

//unzipping a gzipped file
GZIPInputStream in = null;
OutputStream out = null;
try {
   in = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream("file.txt.gz"));
   out = new FileOutputStream("file.txt");
   byte[] buf = new byte[1024 * 4];
   int len;
   while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
       out.write(buf, 0, len);
   }
}
catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
   if (in != null)
       try {
           in.close();
       }
       catch (IOException ignore) {
       }
   if (out != null)
       try {
           out.close();
       }
       catch (IOException ignore) {
       }
}
```

Comment: @StanislavPalatnik probably cause of parts of the code that haven't to do much with the problem ;) (BTW I wasn't a downvoter) catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
   if (in != null)
       try {
           in.close();
       }
       catch (IOException ignore) {
       }
   if (out != null)
       try {
           out.close();
       }
       catch (IOException ignore) {
       }
}

Comment: With Java 9 this can be simplified to `try (InputStream in = new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream("file.txt.gz")); OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("file.txt")) { in.transferTo(out); }`

Answer (score 3):

There may be a library somewhere to make this easy.

However, if there isn't, you can still do it the hard way with the [java.util.zip classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html)... using  [`ZipFile`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) or [`ZipInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html), along with [`ZipEntry`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html) for zip.

[`GZIPInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html) can wrap a `FileInputStream` for gzip, keeping in mind that gzip only works on single files.

Both types of InputStreams also have their respective OutputStreams.

Unfortunately, although I know of these classes, I've never actually *used* them, so I can't advise you any more than that.

Edit: The Zip functions do not appear to have any method for adding new files to a zip file without recreating the entire thing.